# Bulma "is-marginless" class does not remove "margin-right" on container component

Tags: wordpress, css, bulma

I am trying to design a WordPress theme using Bulma.io; I'd like a page with tabs and content inside a `container` div element. When I apply Bulma CSS class `is-marginless`, three margins get overwritten, but `margin-right` is not applied from the class. Adding `style="margin-right: 0px !important;"`, does not affect the visuals either.

To switch between tabs, I use code from [The Internet](https://codepen.io/AnatoliyAV/pen/ZowdRN) which works seamlessly except the `margin-right` issue.

Considering the design is relatively complex already, you can see the [page for yourself](https://2ndlayer.perlur.cloud/about-us/investor-relations/).

[image: Border on the right does not fit the tabs]

As you can see, due to the div element right margin, the border does not meet with the border of the tab lines. I am quite new to Bulma and CSS in general.

When I open Chrome Developer Tools and find a definition of `is-marginless` for a given div, I can see `margin: 0px !important;` is set, but when I click the expand arrow, I can see `margin-right: 0px !important;` crossed out, so it does not apply for some reason, but I can't find out why.

Comment: maybe the active tab has a margin right set. so the selector `tabs tab:active` or `tab.active` is more specific that `tabs tab { margin: 0}` . That might cause the problem. Try to set `margin:0` to the `active` tab. I am sure it has a specific class or something. Search in the dev tools which element has that margin and overwrite it in css.

Comment: I've added `is-fullhd` to the `class` and it fixed the issue, the blocking piece of code has been `max-width: 1152px;` on `container` class, added class increased it to `max-width: 1344px;`, I wonder how the website will look on bigger screens; I'll have to check it somewhere.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: so, it wasn't a margin but a width ? that should've been very ' visible ' in the devtools :) . Anyway, glad i could help

Comment: It used a same orange color as margin uses, so I am not sure how it should be very visible. May be some CSS voodoo that resulted in margin-right: 0px; being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I've added is-fullhd to the class and it fixed the issue, the blocking piece of code has been max-width: 1152px; on container class, added class increased it to max-width: 1344px;